# Double call jquery click

Tags: jquery, click

Good day! Please help, I use nested if triggered the click event in a nested element, the function is called and the external parent. How can I raise an event once for internal?

**Html**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subitem 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("ul li").on("click", function(e){
    alert($("a", this).text());
});
```

Code http://jsfiddle.net/fSkLb/1/

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is for you to prevent propagation of the event to the parent elements

http://jsfiddle.net/fSkLb/3/

```
$("ul li").on("click", function(e){    
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert($("a", this).text());
});
```

Some of the other answers say to use `return false`. I wouldn't suggests that unless you're trying to prevent the link from being followed. `e.stopPropagation` is the way with the least amount of side effects.

Comment: So what you are saying that he would want to go to '#'  ? `return false` is more right than `e.stopPropagation()` here.

Comment: @Jashwant Because in the real world, they would usually have a link so it can work without JS?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of listening on `li`, you can listen to the `a`

```
$("ul li a").on("click", function(e){
    alert($(this).text());
    return false;
});
```

Also, `return false` here stops the propogation.

Comment: This is the cleanest way, and you don't need the `return false`.

Comment: You will need `return false`, else it will propagate.

Comment: Answers without explanations bug me... This works because there are no nested `<a>` tags, therefore there's no problem with bubbling up to the containing `<a>`

Comment: Jashwant, I'm curious why you added that extra block there? My example used karthikr's answer and works fine?

Comment: @Jashwant Your example doesn't make a lot of sense. Karthikr said to use the `a` in the selector, and you're using a selector without an `a` to prove your point. It does show that the solution is brittle though

Comment: I think I got the question wrong. I am assuming that OP had another `click` handler on parent element and does not want to propagate to that event.

Comment: @Jashwant Even though I said "your example doesn't make sense", it does make sense when you explain the fact that this solution would break if there were other listeners on parent elements that shouldn't do anything if the click was on the link... If you see my comment, that's what I'm explaining, this only works because the `a` tag is not nestable

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevents further propagation of the current event. so try this

```
$("ul li").on("click", function(e){
    alert($("a", this).text());
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fSkLb/4/)

Comment: You're not calling `stopPropagation` on the jQuery event object (`e`).

Comment: thanks @jmar777 but i would like to know why `event.stopPropagation()` also working as you can see in fiddle

Comment: what browser are you using? I know IE, for example, has a global `window.event` object that is always equal to the current event.  Not sure about what other browsers have this as well.

Comment: I am using chrome and it'working only here not in IE or Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event's `stopPropagation` method, which will prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree:

```
$("ul li").on("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert($("a", this).text());
});
```

Here's an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fSkLb/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul li").on("click", function(e){
    alert($("a", this).text());
    return false;
});
```

`return false` avoids event bubble. The same can be done with [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Comment: `return false` also stops the default behavior, not necessarily what is being asked

Comment: It may depend on the user's needs. What was asked is to avoid multiple events, not to keep the `a` basic event.

Comment: `e.stopPropagation` answers the question without additional side effects

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer...

```
$("ul li").on("click", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert($("a", this).text());
});
```

Comment: As the 4th person to suggestion `stopPropagation()`, I'd say you're right :)

Comment: you can either use `e.stopPropagation()` or `return false;` .

Comment: `return false` is the same as calling `stopPropagation()` *and* `preventDefault()`. In this case there's no default behavior, so no biggie, but in general it's best to be minimal in how you terminate event behavior.

Comment: @Jashwant, It may be worth expanding on that in your answer, but the question is specifically about preventing the handler from running multiple times with nested elements.